# What do 条件付運航 and 状況待ち mean in practice?

Tags: meaning, expressions

A [ferry company serving Yakushima](https://www.tykousoku.jp/etc/operation.php) offers a real-time status/schedule page with this handy key:

```
○：通常運航
△：条件付運航
※：状況待ち
欠：欠航
```

The first and the last are clear enough (normal operation and cancelled, respectively), but the two in the middle literally translate to "conditional operation" and "waiting for situation".  **What do these mean in practice?**

In their [FAQ](https://faq.skymark.co.jp/app/answers/list/c/593#:%7E:text=%E3%80%8C%E6%9D%A1%E4%BB%B6%E4%BB%98%E3%81%8D%E9%81%8B%E8%88%AA%E3%80%8D%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF,%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E4%BE%BF%E3%81%AE%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%80%82), the airline Skymark suggests 「条件付き運航」 means "will try to operate, but may divert or cancel if the weather gets worse". 「状況待ち」 doesn't have much in the way of relevant hits, but I'd guess it means they haven't made the call on whether to run or cancel yet?

Answer (score 1):

[条件付き](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%9D%A1%E4%BB%B6%E4%BB%98%E3%81%8D) means "conditional, conditionally". It comes from 条件が付く, 付き being the 連用形 of 付く and thus used as a noun/prepositive modifier. The operation is conditional.

From their FAQ:

> Q: 条件付運航とはどういった運航ですか？
>
> A: 悪天候時また台風などで海上が時化の場合、出港はするものの場合によっては引き返す可能性もあるという条件が付いた運航になります。

My translation:

> Q: What kind of operation is "conditional operation"?/What does "conditional operation" mean?
>
> A: When there is a storm at sea caused by inclement weather or typhoon, it is possible that a ferry decides to depart but later returns to the port. That is the condition attached to such ferries.

That is to say if you board such a ferry you accept the condition/caveat that it may have to come back due to inclement weather.

Similarly 状況待ち comes from 状況を待つ, "waiting for information on weather conditions". If a ferry is showing 「状況待ち」 I'd think they have yet to make the call.